# Create a wordpress Shortcode to display category posts

Tags: php, arrays, shortcode, wordpress

Here is what I have so far. I'm in no way a great programmer. Just a front end guy trying to get this to work. I have a website with different blog categories. For example I have a category called: foods, places, things. I'm trying to write a function where I can execute a shortcode like this:

> [list_post mycat="foods"]

Basically I want it to be flexible so whatever category I put inside of "mycat" it will display those blogs.

Again any help would be really appreciated. I know I need to pass a parameter, but I'm honestly unsure how. This is my best effort. Thanks for any hekp

```
    $args = array(
    //Pass parameter here
    //Something like array (
        //$mycat => 'slug';
    //);

    );

function list_post($mycat){


    $query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => $mycat));
    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()):the_post();
            the_title();
        endwhile;
    else:
        echo "No posts found!";
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

add_shortcode('list_post', 'list_post')
```

Comment: **DO NOT** post duplicate questions

Comment: My question is.You use this short code for custom post type or default post ?

Answer (score 0):

Your shortcode accepts 1 argument and it's an array with values inside of it. So for this case, `$mycat` looks like this => `array('mycat' => 'foods');`, So for this instance, you should use the following to extract and compare:

```
function list_post($atts){
    $arr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'mycat' => 'some_default_category',
    ), $atts );
    //now you can call $arr['mycat']; instead of $mycat.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it's still not working I'm not sure if I did it correctly :/

Comment: This is what I did, I'm guessing this is wrong.

 $query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => $arr['mycat']));

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to use [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to achieve this.

```
function list_post($atts){
    $arr = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'mycat' => 'slug',
        ), $atts );

    $args = array('category_name' => $arr['mycat']);
    $out = '';
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if ($posts){
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $out .= $post->post_title . '<br />';
        }
    }
    else {
        $out .= 'No posts found!';
    }
    return $out;

}

add_shortcode('list_post', 'list_post');
```

Note that it is better to return the output from your shortcode and not echo it.

Edit: Removed usage of `extract()` function as per [@PieterGoosen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen) advice.

Comment: You can use `WP_Query` as well. All that `get_posts` does is use `WP_Query`

Comment: Yes. But I feel its easier to use the function. Particularly as it doesn't involve messing up with the global $post variable.

Comment: Your code messed up the `$post` and `$posts` global, so you have broken both, so what are the odds really

Comment: You should also **never ever** use `extract()`.  It is so bad, it has been completely removed from core almost two years ago

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand the messing up of the `$post` and `$posts` global. Can you please explain it a little in detail?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know not to use `extract()`.  I didn't know this all these days. I just came across [this ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400) and [this blog post](https://josephscott.org/archives/2009/02/i-dont-like-phps-extract-function/). Editing my answer right away.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found those posts and now understand why `extract()` is so bad. About the `$post` and `$posts` globals, ask a new question on [wordpress.se] and I'll be happy to answer it. It is quite an extensive discussion that does not fit comments. Also, [wordpress.se] is dedicated to Wordpress and such issues, so you will get really good to the point answers there ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!